# Database selection for performance and scalability for C# APIs

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, cassandra, scalability

I've been working on a project for dating-like app, kind of tinder/bumble. I've been debating which database to use Cassandra or MongoDB. So far I have experience only with MS SQL, mysql and Unidata... I've been looking into Cassandra and MongoDB because of scalability, but I've heard Tinder had issues with their MongoDB, thus they had to call in for help. Even if it is not any of those 2, what else would you suggest? Learning DB would not be an issue for me, but I am looking for performance and scalability. Main programming language will be C# (if it helps) and preferably I am looking for building this in cloud (Azure Cosmos DB, aws dynamoDB or similar). My thoughts are NoSQL DB because of scalability but I wouldn't be opposed to select RDBMS if there is strong reason.

Suggestions, comments, thoughts?

Comment: Just because something is a documentDB or its NoSQL doesn't mean its fast or that it scales. SQL scales pretty well if you implement read/write replicas.

After that you can start implementing caching, you still have sql server for your atomic transactions and for storage. Take the following example/thought, say you have millions of users. When x logs in, retrieve x and store in cache (e.g. redis), everything x does is stored in cache and written to the database. When X logs off or x hasn't visited in a while the cache is invalidated and disappears till he logs on again.

Comment: @Kris.J adding replicas, if it is not async replica, it slows down your insert/update/delete queries. Because it has to commit first to replica for accomplish ACID. And if you make fulltext search with wide variaty columns, you need to index that columns it also slow downs your write/update/delete queries. So it does not magically scale well as you said.

Comment: @Emre Savcı, I'm aware but you wouldn't use async replicas unless the replica was in a remote location.

Comment: Also never meant to imply its magical, just that people have this notion that it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra has some advantages over mongodb.

- There is no master-slave in cassandra. Any node can receive any
  query. If master goes down on mongodb, you'll face with little down time.
- It is easy to scale cassandra, adding a node is not a challange.
- Writes are very fast.
- Read query with primary key is fast.

Also

- There is no aggregation in cassandra
- Bad performance for very high update/delete (increasing tombstones causes bad performance impact : http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html)
- Not efficient for fulltext search applications
- No transactions
- No joins
- Secondary indexes are not equal to rdbs indexes and should not use very often

So you can not use cassandra for every use cases. If your data model does not fit for cassandra just consider another db which fits your requirements.

Also take a look at : https://blog.pythian.com/cassandra-use-cases/

Comment: @OP, you should note that Cassandra doesn't scale magically either, you need to understand that using Lists has an impact on performance due to the way they work, IIRC when you save a List back Cassandra needs to do a Read before it Writes. That your Consistency Level and the Replication Factor you choose are going to adversely affect performance. Also other things such as Maps being slower than sets etc.